# J2ME keyRepeated is not working

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

```
class ClassCanvas extends Canvas{
    private int keyboard_key = 0;
    protected void paint(Graphics g){
        //Never mind the drawing, essence is that keyRepeated isn't working!
        g.drawString(""+keyboard_key,0,0,Graphics.TOP|Graphics.LEFT);
        }
    protected void keyRepeated(int keyCode) {
        keyboard_key = keyCode;
    }
}
```

I compiled that, and paint always draws 0. Like that keyRepeated isn't even executed.

I tested "hasRepeatEvents()"  and it says "true" so why keyRepeated doesn't work?
I'm out of ideas what could be happening.

keyPressed and keyReleased work, but keyRepeated not

Additional info:

- CLDC-1.1,
- MIDlet-2.0
- IDE: Netbeans7.0.1 (or Java(TM) ME
  Platform SDK 3.0)
- Phone: CamshellCldc1, DefaultCldcPhone1 (I
  tested both, both didn't work)

Comment: hasRepeatEvents() give you true, post that code here in question.

Comment: are you sure that you properly "simulate" repeated key presses? did you check ME SDK manuals? these may explain how to get the desired effect in emulator